# Exhaust vibrations/noise

Tags: noise, vw, exhaust, polo

I have had for some time some exhaust noise/vibrations, and decided to buy a new exhaust. However when I checked the exhaust I couldn't find any holes or any bad rubber holders. I decided to not change it and investigate some more.

The noise increased and it seems like the exhaust has been lying on some metal making the noise marked with red. [image: Metal Issue]

I can turn the rubber holders of the exhaust to remove the sound, but how can it be that this is hitting the metal: The image shows the one that has been turned.

[image: Turned rubber]

But this holder and also the other rubber holders look to be fine - to the best of my knowledge. Is there supposed to be rubber on the metal the exhaust is hitting? Or how can this happen?

**After turning**

It seems now the noise has disappeared, and it has not been turning back. I find this really weird how that can happen. Is there some issue with the rubber exhaust hanger? Is it general that they make this noise polos from 2013?

Comment: Looking at the top image ... there appears to be plenty of clearance there. Also, I'm not seeing any indication of fresh metal (metal-to-metal contact would show a fresh, rust free area rubbed into it). I'm wondering how did you came to the conclusion this is where the metal-to-metal contact is happening?

Comment: In the top image, the exhaust looks as though it is not central in the arch it passes through. Perhaps the seam/lip around the end of the can is knocking against the arch, on the left.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I had it lifted up, and the banging noise disappeard as soon as I lifted the exhaust up a bit.

Comment: @WeatherVane I could not see it, but maybe I am misunderstanding what you mean.